# Can I use CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver to CamelCase a string?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to reuse the methods CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver converts property names to strings?

I use CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver as my JsonFormatter for WebApi, which works very well. In another area of my application I dynamically convert some .NET Model Properties to strings to be used in JS. However the strings are Pascal case (as is my .NET standard) and hence in JS cannot be used to directly target JS object properties which have been formatted.

```
// JS Example
var myJsonObject = getJsonObjectFromServer();
var myPropertyString = getPropertyNameFromServer();
var value = myJsonObject[myPropertyString];
// But value cannot be determined as casing of myPropertyString has changed
```

I want to avoid having to create my own ToCamelCase method which could potentially create a different string. I also want to keep using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver (the root of the problem) as the application is quite large now and would require a lot of JS updating and make my js non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

Found the API at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm

```
public string JsonPropertyName
{
    get
    {
        var resolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        return resolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(PropertyName);
    }
}
```